# How do I copy and add a specific imdb ID to another state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

This is the API call i make. 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmys4.png

These are my states. The movies [] contains all the movies of the API call. What I need to do is that I have a button [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg1cB.png) which should copy and add the imdbID from this.state.movies.imdbID to this.state.favorites.

```
        this.state = {
        movie: "Interstellar",
        movies: [],
        movieDetailsVisible: false,
        favorites:[],
    };
```

The way I did it was :

```
const updateFavorites = () => {
this.setState({
    favorites: [...this.state.favorites, this.state.movies.imdbID]
})
console.log(this.state.favorites);
```

}

When i call it from my button (I'm also using ant-design with reactjs):

```
 <Tooltip placement="bottom" title="Add to favorites.">
                <Icon  
                onClick={() => this.updateFavorites()} 
                type="heart-o" />
            </Tooltip>
```

[This is what I get when I press the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgSzT.png)

Answer (score 0):

The function `updateFavorites` is a constant not a class property. That's why when you try to call it this way you get the error.

```
onClick={() => this.updateFavorites()}
```

... instead try this:

```
onClick={updateFavorites}
```

... or make the function a class property:

```
class YourClass {
  updateFavorites = () => {}
}
```